# Good examples of GUI design for business-oriented, heavy data-entry (CRUD) applications

Tags: user-interface, usability, enterprise, crud

Where can I find examples of very well produced enterprise-*y* software that have:

- Good, consistent use of keyboard shortcuts.
- Good keyboard form navigation
- Standarized form validation
- Standarized use of *lookup*/*search* screens. (User gets asked for Client ID, doesn't know it but can look it up from a popup window that returns it)
- Standarized usability/LaF conventions

Would be nice to see samples ranging from simple CRUD screens to very complex process-oriented GUIs for applications like CRM/ERP/Financial/Risk assessment etc.
Basically GUIs with a high amount of entry fields that define certain business process.

Comment: still want to see better and more specific answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't have any examples to point to. In truth, many of these screens may be hard to find on the web for the simple fact that most of them tend to be "ugly". These kinds of screens are rarely pretty.

I can offer some tips, from long history working with these things.

1. **Consistency.** Make everything "work the same", and work the same all the time. Basically, you should be able to do your entry looking at the form, not the screen. All those flashes and subtotals and colors are nice after they keyed the form in, but not during entry itself. There you basically need audio alerts to let them know "something is wrong". The classic "ticky-ticky-ticky-ticky-beep-beep-beep-beep" scenario as the user discovers that they entered a field wrong 4 fields back. The users aren't quite blind, but they're not going to be looking at your screen. The data is on the form.
2. **It's better to work modally, and STOP THEM for ERRORs than let them keep going.** For large forms, scanning all of that information and looking for errors after the fact is very difficult. Stop them when they're wrong so they can fix it and move forward rather than coming back to fix it at the end. The more business rules and validation and enforcement you can have on the form, the better. Popups, alerts, pickers, if it needs their attention, modal modal modal. They're not working with clay here. They're not authoring the great american novel or modeling the global economy.
3. **Summarize the results for spot checks.** For example, keying in an order, they should be able to look at the order total and line item count to see if they got the order in "correctly" as a sort of checksum rather than having to scan their entry field by field. Most workflows have an inevitable cross check phase where they go through their entry to verify the data, but that should be after the "raw keying" of the data.  People work faster when they're in a "bulk entry" mode rather than spot checking each one, each time they key it in. It's breaks their rhythm. Make detecting and correcting the exceptions easier after basic validation and keying is done. If some fields are more important than others (and you know which ones those are), visually highlighting them on the screen AND on the paper form works wonders.

   If the forms and such are designed well (both the computer forms and the paper entry forms), errors should be difficult to enter (like the wrong customer, or wrong item, etc.). You might have a typo in some notes or special instructions, but, not so much everywhere else. If they miskey an item or amount, odds are the order won't total properly so the simple checksum will help them catch it.
4. Going back to "consistency", **make sure things like pickers and such all operate the same.** Try to keep the special functions to a minimum, as it simplifies training and lets users just "flow" in to their work.
5. **Keyboard shortcuts and navigation are a requirement, not an option.** A real pain point here can be detail areas (i.e. table structures). You may need a shortcut to enter and exit the table strcutures. You may have seen a lot of examples where you can "Tab" in to the table, but not tab back out. Have a dedicated "meta-tab" key to move in and out of sections. Requiring the mouse to navigate out of a section is a no no.
6. **Have a single hot key for pickers.** Ideally, they won't have to use these too often. Maybe for customer lookup, most of the other codes they're inevitably memorize or they'll be keyed on the entry form. Make the pickers filterable.
7. **Scrolling is the devil. Scrolling is evil. *No Scrolling!*** Paging better than scrolling because "fields don't move", they're always "in the same spot" on the screen. How often have you "scrolled" and had to search to pick up "where you started" before the scroll to regain context. Even for pick lists paging works very well because the page change lets them know they actually "did something" visually. Many times you scroll a row and "gee did I really?" Single line scrolling can be too subtle. For large entry forms, multi-pages beats long, scrolling treatises every day of the week. If your forms are that big, make sure you have a hot key to move forward and backwards through the form, and make sure there is some context information on each page (customer name, order number, whatever...simple header).
8. **Robust querying.** "Query by example" as it's known is one of the best mechanisms (i.e. they fill it the form "what they know" and forms come back). Folks need to find data by just crazy criteria, if most every field is queryable, this lets them do that without you second guessing what they will or won't need. Informix 4GL used to have a spectacular QBE system (`> 04/01/09` for dates after Apr 1 2009, `12345|23456` for item codes 12345 or 23456). A good QBE expression will most likely not validate in a typical field, it's a special case. (Which is why you rarely see QBE today, it takes too much work -- but it is OH so nice.)
9. Remember, **users don't know *WHY* or *HOW* they do things, they only know *WHAT* to do.** They know *"when I want to do A, I hit key <kbd>Y</kbd>"* they don't know WHY it's Y, where Y is located, the keys X an Z might do similar things to A because they're grouped together. No, they don't know your command taxonomy. They don't know your abstractions. They know to do A, hit <kbd>Y</kbd>. Want to Bold a word? Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. Maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to italicize a word is obvious to you because of the mnemonic, it's not to most users. Maybe the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> are on the `Format` menu, nicely grouped. Doesn't matter. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> == Bold, how do I do Italics?

The downside of these interfaces is training. They do take training in order for them to be used. But, in truth, for any reasonably complicated business, the user is going to need training on far more than just the keying process anyway. The entry screen isn't going to teach them the business policies, business rules, etc. You can enforce these in the application, but the user is going to need to know them on their own anyway.

But that's OK, because in the long run it's simply more efficient. The game here is getting the data from the user efficiently and presenting it to them in a consistent way. I won't say "logical" way, as, while logic may be logic, it may not be the users logic. So, you can be logical if you want, call it what you want, but be consistent to your users.

Another anecdote, we used to 10 key return data. This tended to be just lists of number, like an item code and a quantity. For our purposes it's faster to simply have the users key this data twice in a row than anything else. It catches typos, transpositions, etc. Combined with batch checksums makes the keying go that much faster. These guys only looked at the screens when they started, when they finished, and if they got an error.

Finally, no matter what, your screens and procedures *WILL* change. Whatever form you're using this year, will change next year. That's just reality, so, FYI, be ready for it.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: This is a great summary, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanx for the formatting, @voyager, looks great.

Comment: @Will Hartung: my pleasure :)

Comment: Wow, what a great, great, great answer. +8!  (that's an infinity, turned sideways)

Answer (score 5):

I am a fan of the http://www.37signals.com/ suite. I find their forms and GUI's to be well thought out.

Comment: Yes, they're very well produced, but they don't really have the kind of screens I'm looking for (the ones you see in complex CRM/ERP apps mainly)

Comment: @Camilo: Maybe you should consider 37signals' Getting Real (http://gettingreal.37signals.com/) approach given that there seems to be a lot of complexity in your apps. Getting Real will help you design effective and useful UI that keeps users happy.

Comment: @CamiloDíaz that's funny because one of their apps is a CRM.

Answer (score 3):

You know, there is [Openerp](http://www.openerp.com/) that you can get program, source ,doc for free.

ps: this link is OK to me, if you cannot open it, search openerp in google.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted you but your link is broken.

Comment: I can goto that address, I think it is your problem cannot open the link. go search openerp in google, see if you can open the link.

Comment: The servers are a little slow, but I can open the link just fine. However, I'm not too impressed by their interface.

Answer (score 3):

I have used lots -- but its difficult to remeber any specific app as really good UIs are prety much forgetable.

I can remember lots of bad ones. Anyone who bitches about lotus notes has obviously never used any SAP or ORACLE forms based apps.

For sheer efficiency I would suggest you look at the old SABRE airline reservation application. Two lines of text no spaces or other punctuation

First line the flight second line payment details something like this would book and pay for a flight:

```
123109BA176Y
276.00GBPAM1122123412341234
```

travel agents became addicated to it and for years refused to accept the super duper windows GUI replacement firing up the green screen terminal emulater instead. I think it only died the death when airlines switched to three letter codes and four digit flight numbers.

Comment: Correction. I booked a flight last week and the agent fired up the "green screen" interface just like his father before him.

Answer (score 2):

I find the [Dashboard Spy website](http://www.enterprise-dashboard.com/) to be one of the best for inspiration.

Comment: From a strictly aesthetic point of view...

Answer (score 2):

Here's examples of what not to do!: [Worst UI You’ve Ever Used](http://web.archive.org/web/20100715232035/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used)

Answer (score 1):

You should really visit the [Interface Hall of Shame](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/shame.htm), where you'll find not only the most bizarre GUIs ever conceived, but also possible solutions to the usability problems they generate.

Comment: The link given in answer is broken..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider 37signals' [Getting Real](http://gettingreal.37signals.com)  approach given that there seems to be a lot of complexity in your apps. Getting Real will help you design effective and useful UI that keeps users happy.